# Passing self as a parameter to be set as delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to pass "self", so that it can be set as delegate.

For example

```
func getBanerView(in view : UIView, self : parameterType)-> GADBannerView{
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    ***bannerView.delegate = self***

    return bannerView
}
```

how do i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Pass Parameter type `AnyObject`

Comment: You also need to have your superclass inherit from the delegate you're using: `class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate` or whatever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func getBanerView(in view : UIView, delegate: GADBannerViewDelegate)-> GADBannerView {

   view.addSubview(bannerView)
   bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
   bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
   bannerView.delegate = delegate

   return bannerView
}
```

Then call

```
getBanerView(*someView*, delegate: self)
```

Hope it help. :)